# How to make a "like" query in Parse.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

For example, If my database is:

```
{
    people: name: [{"first":"Billy", "last":"smith"}]
},
{
    people: name: [{"first":"bob", "last":"smith"}]
},
{
    people: name: [{"first":"thor", "last":"smith"}]
},
{
    people: name: [{"first":"hobo", "last":"smith"}]
}
```

I would like something to the effect of: `query.like("b")` and have it return the first, second and fourth docs

Is there anything like this in the Javascript API?

Comment: Related: https://www.parse.com/questions/are-like-or-regex-queries-possible-via-the-rest-api

Comment: So the Javascript query.startsWith() function would have only gotten "billy" and "bob". Not "hobo". So it's lacking in that regard.

Answer (score 10):

The [`contains(key, substring)`](http://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#contains) method is the one you want, but note that this will only match on the second and fourth docs.

The reason is that searches are case-sensitive. A common tactic is to add a Cloud Code handler to write searchable content to another field [before save](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-modifysave), e.g.:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("people", function(request, response) {
    request.object.set(
        "search_name", 
        request.object.get("first").toLowerCase() 
            + " " 
            + request.object.get("last").toLowerCase()
    );
    response.success();
});
```

Now you can use `query.contains("search_name", searchString.toLowerCase())` to find them all.

If you want to be able to search on just the first-name and not the last-name, either add another field ("search_first"), or just modify the above, depending on your needs.

Comment: Won't I lose the cases, then, in the Document?

Comment: You keep your original "first" & "last" fields, and add an additional "search_name" field that has a copy of those values converted to lower case.