# Can I not use a string value to query a match against an object held in parse.com data object?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Parse.com and JavaScript SDK.

Is it not possible to complete an `equalTo` query using a JavaScript string in Parse?

I want to compare the username of what the user has clicked on and has been stored in the variable to that of the username in my Parse class.

Do I need to save the string into Parse before being able to run a query?

Code is below.

`username` is a pointer field held in the `myBadges` class, it points to `_User`.

`friendName` is the value held in the string and does not exist in Parse.

I thought if I was just querying against `friendName` then it would'nt need to exist?

```
function friendFeed() {
    var friendActivity = $('friendName').text();
    console.log(friendName);
    var FriendFeeds = Parse.Object.extend("myBadges");
    var query = new Parse.Query(FriendFeeds);
    query.include('username'); 
    query.equalTo('username', friendName); // find users that match

    query.find({
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue in that Parse string matches are case-sensitive. Here's an answer I provided to a similar issue:

[How to make a "like" query in Parse.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248563/how-to-make-a-like-query-in-parse-com/19259770#19259770)

To enable case-insensitive searches, you'll want to create a `beforeSave` Cloud Code method that adds an extra property with a lower-case version of the `username`, e.g.:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("myBadges", function(request, response) {
    var myBadges = request.object;
    myBadges.set("username_search", myBadges.get("username").toLowerCase());
    response.success();
});
```

Then just change your query to work against the new `username_search` property instead, being careful to use `.toLowerCase()` on the user-input first of course.