# How to search for a substring (WHERE column LIKE '%foo%')

Tags: parse-platform

I'm reading parse API documentation at https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#queries and can't find how to search by a substring. SQL equivalent would be:

```
... WHERE column_name LIKE "%foo%"
```

There's a bunch of options such as &gt, &lt, &in, and similar, but there's no option for LIKE. It's pretty common use case... What am I missing?

Comment: What are you developing with? Android, iOS, JS?

Comment: Web app for mobile devices. We're using the parse.com REST API: https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide/ My question is about lack of LIKE lookups in the API (or maybe they did not document it?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've found something that looks like an **undocumented feature**.

There's a $regex lookup it's not mentioned in the official API reference. It allows for matching by regular expressions which solved the problem for us.

We believe it should be documented here:

https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide/#queries-query-constraints

But apparently it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I think you should follow Parse's tutorial here: http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/implementing-scalable-search-on-a-nosql-backend/

It is very helpful in terms of search. The main ideas are:

- Separate the texts into single words and store as in array
- Then perform search on the new field using `containedIn`(or `$in` as in REST API) query.

There's also a question regarding this too: [How to make a "like" query in Parse.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248563/how-to-make-a-like-query-in-parse-com)

EDIT: New blog link: https://web.archive.org/web/20150416171914/http://blog.parse.com/2013/03/19/implementing-scalable-search-on-a-nosql-backend/

Comment: As far as I understand, it would only allow for finding a full word in text, whereas I would like to be able to find any substring. For example if I have a record "Television is nice" then I would like to be able to search for "%vision%" and it get a match. 

The idea to manually split text into array just to allow for text searching seems very weird. Database backend should support LIKE operator out of the box without requiring developers to pre-process and prepare the text before inserting it to the database...

Comment: Ok.. Rather than separating words, you can make the sentence lowercase. Check the link in my answer. `contains` is used as LIKE operator.

Comment: Blog Link is dead.  Takes you to the front of the ParsePlatform blog.  There is no search from said page.  Demonstration of why not to let links do the work for you.  However, you did include the 'containedIn' piece, which will help lead to the answer, so thank you.